# Jenkins doesn't catch timezone of my base OS

Tags: linux, jenkins, java-8, debian

I've been struggling with one issue that Jenkins doesn't want to see the default host timezone. Does anybody know why it happens? I setup correct date and time on my server based on Debian 12. After installing and running Jenkins, it displays UTC in `jenkinsserver/systemInfo`. I know the settings might be applied manually by a drop-in file into **systemd** with `JAVA_OPTS` arguments:

```
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York"
```

```
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=America/New_York"
```

I don't want to go this way and I'm currently trying to understand why Jenkins doesn't catch all settings from my underlying OS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For debian based systems, it's necessary to run the following command and restart Jenkins service:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

After that, you will see the right timzeone in your `jenkinsserver/systemInfo`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).